# Awaitable methods in "if" condition - does execution wait for result of the method

Tags: c#, async-await

Does this code make sense:

```
if (await CheckCondition1())
{
    Work1();
}
if (await CheckCondition2())
{
    Work2();
}
if (await CheckCondition3())
{
    Work3();
}
```

As awaited method is in `if` statement, does execution wait for result before going to next lines? Or will it rather result in calling "CheckCondition 1-3" methods in background and perform "Work" methods when results are ready?

In other words, if "CheckConditions" are long-running, will they be executed in parallel, or will they be executed sequentially as if it was synchronous code?

Comment: The `await` will be waited for before the following `await` calls are waited for. However, in an application with a UI the UI can still be doing stuff before the `await` has returned - but in the method with the `await` calls they will be executed sequentially.

Comment: If gets compiled to (more or less) `var b1 = await Check1(); if (b1) { ... }`.`await` alone won't make your code suddenly multithreaded, it just offloads work after the `await` and leaves until that call returns.

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you , await, means await

Comment: @TheGeneral aand awhat await ameans? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three "check" methods are executed one after another (because of the await). If you want to execute them in parallel, you have to call these methods and await them after you called all of them:

```
Task<bool> task1 = CheckCondition1();
Task<bool> task2 = CheckCondition2();
Task<bool> task3 = CheckCondition3();
if(await task1)
{
   Work1();
}
if(await task2)
{
   Work2();
}
if(await task3)
{
   Work3();
}
```

Comment: Before awaiting each task individually, it's a good idea to await all of them, in order to avoid leaking fire-and-forget tasks in case the `task1` or `task2` fails: `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);`